# Таймер в приложении на JavaFX

Tags: javafx, таймер

Необходимо вставить в приложение таймер, который будет показывать оставшееся время пользователю. То есть, допустим, пользователь запускает тест, запускается таймер на пять минут. И каждую минуту в лэйбл показывается сколько минут осталось. Интерфейс написан JavaFX. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Помогите.

Сделал через TimerTask:

```
public class Updater extends TimerTask {


UserTestController contr;
private int maxTime;

public Updater(UserTestController contr, int mT){
    this.contr = contr;
    this.maxTime = mT;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    Platform.runLater(() -> contr.showTimer(maxTime));
  }
}
```

В контроллере:

```
public void showTimer(int maxTime) {
    int minutes;
    int seconds = (SECONDS_IN_MINUTES - 1) - clockCount % SECONDS_IN_MINUTES;
    String extraStr = String.valueOf(seconds);

    clockCount++;
    minutes = (maxTime - 1) - clockCount / SECONDS_IN_MINUTES;

    if (seconds < 10) {
        extraStr = "0" + extraStr;
    }
    clockLabel.setText("Осталось времени: " + String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + extraStr);

    if(minutes < 0){
        finishTest();
    }
}
```

Запуск в контроллере:

```
    clockCount = 0;
    updater = new Updater(this, timeOnTestInMinutes);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(updater, 0, 1000);
```

Остановка:

```
public void finishTest() {
    clockLabel.setText("Тест окончен!");
    timer.cancel();
    updater.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно задать

```
int[] time = {5}; //Чтобы внутри события был доступен, делаем в виде массива.
label.setText("5");
```

затем поставить таймер

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline (
    new KeyFrame (
        Duration.millis(1000 * 60), //1000 мс * 60 сек = 1 мин
        ae -> {
            time[0]--;
            label.setText("" + time);
        }
    )
);

timeline.setCycleCount(5); //Ограничим число повторений
timeline.play(); //Запускаем
```