# Как создать всплывающее окно, чтобы через n-cекунд исчезло?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть `TableView`. Создал для `TableCell factorycell`, в котором поставил хендлеры на нажатие левой кнопки мыши, которые копируют в буфер обмена текст из ячейки.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким методом модно создать такое окно, чтобы выводилось сообщение *"Скопировано в буфер обмена"* и затем исчезала. Диалоговое окно не подходит, так как никаких взаимодействий с этим всплывающим сообщением не должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много вариантов.

1 - Показывать сообщение из трея https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571329/javafx-app-in-system-tray

2 - С помощью таймера https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487645/how-to-make-a-label-visible-for-a-certain-time-and-then-should-be-invisible-with

3 - Создать собственную небольшую панель , которая будет открываться при создании экземпляра отдельного класса, и там её так же, двигать при помощи таймера [Таймер в приложении на JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487183/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javafx)

4 - Ещё можно посмотреть в сторону Task, но это посложнее и код более громоздкий выйдет.

Пример использования :

P.S В моем случае размер фрейма жестко фиксирован, и достается справа налево.

```
  public class SlideModalError {

    private static TranslateTransition showStatus;
    public volatile static TranslateTransition hideStatus;
    public volatile static boolean showsStatus = false;


    public SlideModalError(Pane pane){
        setDefaultForPane(pane);
    }
    
    public SlideModalError(String message, Pane pane){
        showAndHideMessage(message,pane);
    }
    
    private void setDefaultForPane(Pane pane){
        pane.setLayoutX(2000);
        pane.setLayoutY(5);
        pane.setPrefSize(440,125);

        showStatus = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(360),pane);
        showStatus.setByX(-1130.0);
        showStatus.setOnFinished(event -> showsStatus = true);
        hideStatus = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50),pane);
        hideStatus.setByX(1130.0);
        hideStatus.setOnFinished(event -> showsStatus = false);
    }
    
    private void showAndHideMessage(String message, Pane pane){
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setLayoutX(25);
        label.setLayoutY(20);

        label.setFont(Font.font("FreeMono", 14));
        label.setTextFill(Color.web("#fffb03"));
        label.setText(message);

        pane.setPrefSize(440,(55+message.length()/2));

        pane.getChildren().clear();


        pane.getChildren().add(label);
        
        // Бывает так, что только только сообщение хочет скрыться
        // но пользователь что-то делает... 
        // Так Pane никуда не двигается 
        // Или наоборот возвращается на исходную в случае ERROR
        
        if(showsStatus){return;}
        if(pane.getLayoutX()<700){
            pane.setLayoutX(2000);
        }
        
        //

        showStatus.play();
        showsStatus = true;
        // Класс который скроет обратно наш Pane
        SlideLiveTimer slt = new SlideLiveTimer();
        Thread thread = new Thread(slt);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Класс SlideLiveTimer

```
public class SlideLiveTimer extends Task<Void> {

    public static volatile int counts;


    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        counts = 0;
        while (counts<100){
            Thread.sleep(125);
            counts++;
        }


        SlideModalError.hideStatus.play();
        SlideModalError.showsStatus = false;


        return null;
    }
}
```

Чтобы использовать :

```
       // Инициализировать позицию и тайм-лайны
        new SlideModalError(flow_Message);
        // Послать сообщение и скрыть с помощью Task
        new SlideModalError("Сообщение ",flow_Message);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо,  с половиной вопроса касающегося времени я понял, а вот с самим сообщением подскажите, его как лучше создать, я понять не могу. Просто `Label` в виде блока или типо того. 
Чтобы просто без кнопок и меню чисто текст(мб с фоном)

Comment: @ДимаВасильев Всё зависит от вашего воображения, я предоставил вам пример. Но все же надеюсь, что вы придумаете что-нибудь сами )

Comment: Большое спасибо